# rviz_cfg for hector_slam

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch points to an rviz_cfg folder in the hector_slam_launch folder, but no such folder or mapping_demo.rviz file exists after install of hector_slam. I've generated the mapping_demo.rviz file to match the older mapping_demo.cfg file (I just have this on my desktop for now) but I want to verify how to add the rviz_cfg directory to the hector_slam_launch folder along with the .rviz file under the new ROS Indigo format.

OR, is this even the correct protocol under Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194885/rviz_cfg-for-hector_slam/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2014-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the rviz configs are present in the source version of hector_slam_launch, but aren't installed properly.

You should open a bug on the hector_slam repository about this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2014-10-14**:
Thanks. I submitted the issue on the GitHub site.